# Open XML with jQuery with maximum browser compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

We have a webpage using this code :

```
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
// XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
// Create the XHR object.   
xhr.open("GET","prp.xml", false);
xhr.send();
xmlDoc=xhr.responseXML;
```

It opens an XMLHttpRequest to get our XML file and then drops the result into the xmlDoc variable. I would like to know if it's possible to do that same operation using jQuery v1.11.0 and that the xmlDoc variable will still be usable by the rest of the code (aka still compatible with regular JS).

Depending on the user in here, people are using Firefox, Chrome, internet explorer 8, 9 or 10. I have read that internet explorer under 10 cannot use XMLHttpRequest, and i am pretty bad/lost with this whole jQuery thingy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how regular JS handles XML, but an Ajax-call via jQuery is as simple as:

```
var xhr_variable;
$.ajax({
url: "your.xml",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("working");
      xhr_variable = data;
    }, error: function(err) {
      console.log("not working");
}
});
```

If you are new to Ajax, I recommend using error to check if it works or not. If works without problem, you can use the following:

```
var xhr_variable;
$.ajax({
    url: "miep.xml",
    success: function(data) {
        xhr_variable = data;
    }
});
```

Your XML-file will be assigned to your variable (if used in the correct scope).

Please note that for security reasons Ajax will only work if you call documents that are hosted on the same domain. (example.com can get documents for example.com, but not from example2.com).

Comment: Hey man Thanks! Really appreciated. Tough i have a question for you : That code is for picking up some files. How about dropping some strings value into a file using ajax? I know this is not part of the question, but i know that native javascript ajax request may write on the remote server using "POST" command (i think, never used it) Can we do that using jQuery as well so it works with every browser? Thanks again man, really appreciated.

Comment: Sure, you can use it for all sorts of infomation: xml, html, scripts, json, text...
If you just want to load a string, you will need to add the dataType as jQuery by default can only detect xml, json, scripts or html. Just add `dataType: "text",` after the line of the url, and you will be fine. One awesome thing about jQuery is that all versions 1.x work back to IE 6. (2.x-serie is for IE 8+)